# Re-design woocommerce - archive-product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to re-design the page that shows all the products in the a single category, I saw the `taxonomy-product_cat.php` but its just calling the `archive-product.php` file.

after I re-desinged the page, I wonder which variable holding the array with all the products in the current category ? I noticed that line:

```
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
```

is calling the products in the current category page, but how can I fetch the data differently over my way ?
- a way to get the array of products would be perfect!

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

For a custom Woocommerce templates.

Create in your theme (wp-content/themes/{your_theme_name}/ ) a folder called "woocommerce" and copy there the content of wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/* .

Then modify the file content-product.php in your custom woocommerce template. (wp-content/themes/{your_theme_name}/woocommerce/content-product.php )

Comment: That wasn't what I asked for ... as I said I want to get an array of all the products of the current category page. `/?product_cat=icecream`

Comment: Ah ok. Inside the archive-product.php file the query has been done, so you could gather the information calling `<?php $posts = get_posts() ?>`

Or in your template you can query them `$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'category' => 'icecream' ); $posts = get_posts( $args );`

Comment: well, `get_posts()` just giving all posts .. not the current one .. and when I tried
  `$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'category' => woocommerce_page_title() ); 
  $posts = get_posts( $args );` also showing all posts (even regular posts that has to do nothing with woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done this way,

```
$args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => woocommerce_page_title() );
$products = get_posts( $args );
```

`woocommerce_page_title()` return the current page title (which is also the name of the category) so that you will be able to fetch the products from the current page category, 
`$products` is holding the WP_Post Object which contains all the products in the current page category, so you will be able to fetch the data the way you want in you'r web deisgn style.
have in tmind that `get_posts()` whichout the args will give you everything that is post type (which isnt relevent to this case as we want only products of a specific category).

** pay attention to this one **
`product_cat` in the query, let you decide by which category you would like to fetch the products from.